# C - how to read input from text file to 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, input, scanf

I'm trying to read input from a text file to a 2D array. Each number should be a different element in the 2D array. I don't know if I'm using fscanf() wrong here, but the values in the 2D array are wrong.

**Example text file:**

```
623
151
111
```

**Minimal code example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void load_map()
{
    FILE *input;
    int MAXCOLS = 3;
    int MAXROWS = 3;
    int M[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];

    input = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    for(int row = 0; row < MAXROWS; row++ )
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < MAXCOLS; col++ )
        {
            int count = fscanf( input, "%d", &M[row][col] );
            printf("row: %i, col: %i == %i\n", row, col, M[row][col]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{    
    load_map();

    return 0;
}
```

**This outputs:**

```
row: 0, col: 0 == 623
row: 0, col: 1 == 151
row: 0, col: 2 == 111
row: 1, col: 0 == 0
row: 1, col: 1 == 1
row: 1, col: 2 == 0
row: 2, col: 0 == 4196253
row: 2, col: 1 == 0
row: 2, col: 2 == 0
```

So it seems like fscanf() reads the whole line, how can I get the numbers to read individually to the 2D array?

**What I want is:**

```
row: 0, col: 0 == 6
row: 0, col: 1 == 2
row: 0, col: 2 == 3
row: 1, col: 0 == 1
row: 1, col: 1 == 5
row: 1, col: 2 == 1
row: 2, col: 0 == 1
row: 2, col: 1 == 1
row: 2, col: 2 == 1
```

Comment: `"%d"` --> `"%1d"`

Comment: Check the value of `count`. Print the values if `count == 1`, and print "error" otherwise. Can you tell us what the output is now?

Comment: BTW, you have 3 numbers in the input file, yet, you are attempting to read 9. Why do you expect this to do the job???

Comment: @BLUEPIXY that did the trick. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Can't believe I was stuck for hours on this..